# MATLAB: How to write a five-point derivative transfer function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm testing some transfer functions in discrete time (Fs = 200) that I've read from a paper. I don't know how to write a a five-point derivative transfer function for then plot it in a Bode diagram.

The transfer function is:

[transfer function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtnRi.jpg)

I don't know to put positive and negatives esponents at the same time...

T is the sample time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have positive non-zero exponents only, you could multiply by `z^3`. Matlab does the same. (Though I thought you had to multiply by by `z^-3`to make all exponents negative...)

```
Z = tf('z', 1/200)

Z =

  z

Sample time: 0.005 seconds
Discrete-time transfer function.

>> H = (1/8*(1/200))/(-Z^-2 - 2*Z^-1 + 2*Z^1 + Z^2)

H =

       0.000625 z^3
  -----------------------
  z^5 + 2 z^4 - 2 z^2 - z

Sample time: 0.005 seconds
Discrete-time transfer function.
```